# NHibernate - getting one-to-many

Tags: c#, nhibernate

Wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction..

I currently have the following 3 tables in my sqlserver database

Parameter
ParameterId
ParameterName

ParameterValue
ParameterValueId
ParameterValue

ParameterParameterValue
ParameterId
ParameterValueId

I'm trying to get it where the Parameter domain object will also fetch all the ParameterValue objects as well (I'm guessing Parameter has a one-to-many relationship with ParameterValue, since a parameter can have more than one value) but I'm getting no where - the msot I've achieved is fetching the first value, rather than all :(

If anyone is willing to help or anything I can post some code and/or the mappings I'm using - as always, any help is much appreciated :)

Mappings for Parameter

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" 
               namespace="StockMarketAdvisorDatabaseAccess.Domain" 
               assembly="StockMarketAdvisorDatabaseAccess">
<class name="Parameter" table="Parameter">
        <id name="ParameterId">
            <column name="ParameterId" sql-type="int" not-null="true" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <property name="ParameterName" />
        <bag name="ParameterValues" table="ParameterParameterValue" cascade="none">
            <key column="ParameterValueId" />
            <one-to-many class="ParameterValue" />
        </bag>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Mappings for ParameterValue

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" 
                   namespace="StockMarketAdvisorDatabaseAccess.Domain" 
                   assembly="StockMarketAdvisorDatabaseAccess">
    <class name="ParameterValue" table="ParameterValue">
        <id name="ParameterValueId">
            <column name="ParameterValueId" sql-type="int" not-null="true" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <property name="Value" column="ParameterValue"/>
     </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Thanks again, just started using nHibernate so still trying to figure most it out! :)

Comment: The mappings would be very helpful. This actually looks like a many-to-many relationship; a ParameterValue can be used as the value for many different Parameters, and a Parameter can have many values at once. ParameterParameterValue is your cross-reference table, turning the many-to-many into two one-to-many relationships. NHibernate can map this relationship very easily.

Comment: Definitely need to see your mappings. If it's loading one but not all of the many.. then it's most likely a problem with your mappings.

Comment: Yeah, I can see myself where its going wrong, but whenever I try to fix it I get a load of errors - I'm guessing I need to add a mapping in each file to link it to the reference table somehow?

Comment: Yeah got it working by changing it to a many-to-many instead, now it appears to be fetching all the values for the associated parameter :)

Comment: Actually I spoke to soon... I can retreieve the values and parameters correctly, I just can't save them! Can save the parameter and parameterValuie to the correct tables, just not inserting the  values in the reference table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is you are describing one thing (1-many) but your table structure is another (many-many)

If you need many values per parameter then you should simplify your table structure to:

> Parameter
>   -------------
>   * ParameterId
>   ParameterName
>   
>   ParameterValue
>   --------------------
>   * ParameterValueId
>   ParameterId
>   ParameterValue

Then your mapping can use a 1-many mapping:

```
<class name="Parameter" table="Parameter">
    <id name="ParameterId">
        <column name="ParameterId" sql-type="int" not-null="true" />
        <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <property name="ParameterName" />
    <bag name="ParameterValues" table="ParameterValue" cascade="none">
        <key column="ParameterId" />
        <one-to-many class="ParameterValue" />
    </bag>
</class>
```

Comment: Yeah I was thinking of doing that, figured I would try and figure out how to do it as it sits at the minute just for the learning experience :)!